# MySql database and qt

Tags: mysql, linux, qt, lamp

I haven't used databases in linux yet and I'm interested can I use mysql database build in lamp with Qt? I wont to install lamp server to use for web sites but can I use it as a server for database for application build in Qt?

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible, but why use lamp and not just installing the Linux-distribution provided sql server? Nevertheless you will have to build the sqldrivers fitting your system if they are not present.

Comment: How to check if my linux distribution has sql server installed?

Comment: 'ps -ef| grep mysql' run this !

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between installing MySQL as part of a development stack or installing it by itself. In either case you should be asked for an administrative username and password, which, once provided, will let you connect to and query the database with your Qt MySQL backend.